# tesseract APIs with OpenMp: sometimes segmentation faults, sometimes not

Tags: c++, tesseract

I'm writing a small demo with tesseract APIs to run in parallel via OpenMp; it is basically an example taken from tesseract APIs usage page, with some openmp flavour added on it.
The executable takes two arguments: a tif file and an integer for the page to be *ocrized*.

I'm compiling like this:
`clang-omp++ -o tessapi-quality tessapi-quality.cpp -<TESSERACT_FLAGS> -O3 -fopenmp  -g`.

**The problem I'm facing is** that it works most of the time, but one over five - more or less - it throws a seg fault.

I tried and debug with `gdb`, but couldn't find out, 'cause it dies sometimes on a *tesseract baseapi* function, sometimes on another.

Unfortunately I cannot install `valgrind` on the machine where I'm working on now.

I'm aware that it's not handy to be tested from anyone who has not tesseract installed, but maybe I'm missing something big in the code and you can help me just taking a look.

This is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <leptonica/allheaders.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <tesseract/api/baseapi.h>

void getCompImage(const char* filename, int page){
  Pix* image;
  Pixa** pixa;
  int** blockids;
  image = pixReadTiff(filename, page);

  int num_threads = 4;
  omp_set_num_threads(num_threads);

#pragma omp parallel 
{
    tesseract::TessBaseAPI *papi = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
    if (papi->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
#pragma omp critical
        {
            std::cout << "Could not initialize tesseract " << '\n';
        }
        exit(1);
    }

    papi->SetImage(image);
    Boxa* boxes = papi->GetComponentImages(tesseract::RIL_TEXTLINE, true, pixa, blockids);
#pragma omp barrier

#pragma omp for schedule(static) 
    for (int i = 0; i < boxes->n; i++) {
        BOX* box = boxaGetBox(boxes, i, L_CLONE);
        papi->SetRectangle(box->x, box->y, box->w, box->h);
        char* ocrResult = papi->GetUTF8Text();
        int my_thread = omp_get_thread_num();
#pragma omp critical
        {
            std::cout << "Thread: " << my_thread << " Page: " << page << " Box[" << i << "] text: " << ocrResult << "\n";
        }
    }
    // Destroy used object and release memory
    papi->End();
}

  pixDestroy(&image);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    if (argc != 3){
        printf("Type the (tiff) file name to OCRize\n"
                "Then the page in the file to OCRize (first page=0, second=1 etc..)\n\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int page = atoi(argv[2]);

    getCompImage(argv[1], page);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: On a Mac, but I ran almost the same code with the same problem months ago on a Linux box.

Comment: I am kind of uneasy with `-O3` and `-g` at the same time - I normally go for the former for production builds and the latter for debug builds. Also, you could try building with the `gcc` compiler which you can install with `homebrew` using `brew install gcc --without-multilib` and then compiling with `g++-5 -std=c++11 -fopenmp -O3 demo.cpp -o demo`

Comment: @bio Using clang, you can't meaningfully use `-g` and `-O` at the same time, I suggest you install gcc. Also, possibly try running under `setarch -R` (which is part of what gdb does) and/or using valgrind or ASAN or UBSAN or ...

Comment: Both totally right about using optimisation with `-g`.
I'll try and install gcc either, many thanks.

Comment: Installed g++, now I compile like this:
`g++-5  -o tessapi-quality tessapi-quality.cpp -I/usr/local/include/tesseract -L/usr/local/lib -llept -ltesseract  -fopenmp  -g`
It seems much better, because I can't see a seg fault anymore :/
I'm afraid it is something *tesseract* related, since the debugger was telling me it was a pointer freed but never allocated, and I can't see such an error in the code above.